# Small syntax error on displaying a feed element that contains ":"

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to show some info from a feed and I have problem on showing the `<dc:creator>` because of the `:`

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   ':'

For the title I use `entry->title;`

Thank you.

Comment: What are you using to parse the xml?

Comment: I use `$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`simplexml_load_file()` seems to struggle with namespaces, which is what the `:` indicates. If you use [DOM](https://www.php.net/dom) instead, you should be fine:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load($feed);
```